# Remove image URL on small screens using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm trying to pull some cross device trickery. What I want is to remove a slider image for small screen widths (<622px). I have tested, and seen that removing the image URL in CSS creates the effect I want.

**My approach is this...**

Enqueue a .js file in Wordpress to detect when the screen is resized to smaller than 622 px in width, then use .js to remove the slider image url with CSS.

**My implementation...**

**Enqueue the script in functions.php**

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {

    // Register and Enqueue a Script
        wp_register_script('screensizemods', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/screensizemods.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('screensizemods');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

**My script /js/screensizemods.js**

```
function Resize() {
     width = window.innerWidth;
     height = window.innerHeight;

     if(width < 622) {
          // Modify particular Stylesheet elements.

    document.styleSheets[0].addRule('background-image: url("");}');             
     }
}
```

But it's not working. And I'm not getting any console .js errors. I can see the the .js is being loaded. Is there a problem with my .js code?

Edit:

Here is the element I am trying to change. It looks like the Theme is rendering it in-line...

```
element {
    background-image: url("http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/bgimage.jpg");
```

Edit 2:

**OK here's my media query with a watcher attempt...**

It's firing correctly when the screen resizes. But I get an error `reference error: style is not defined`

```
     // media query event handler
    if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 622px)");
    mq.addListener(screensizemods);
    screensizemods(mq);
    }

    // media query change
    function screensizemods(mq) {

    if (mq.matches) {
        // window width is at least 622px
    }
    else {
        // window width is less than 622px
            // push a new rule onto the top of my stylesheet
            style.css.insertRule("background-image: url('') !important}", 0); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a media query?

Comment: Are you sure it’s `addRule` and not [`insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)? Your usage isn’t really correct…

Comment: @Xufox I tried insertRule just now and it didn't work. Yep I know I'm not doing it right. That's why I'm here :)

Comment: @square_eyes By incorrect usage I mean the missing selector + `{` and the missing index. It’s documented on the MDN page I linked.

Comment: @ceejayoz sounds good. I like the idea of listening too. I found this http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/ ... but can't see where I would actually remove the image URL. I'm new to javascript.

Comment: @ceejayoz see my Edit 2 for this attempt. I think I am close.

Comment: @square_eyes No need for JS at all. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best handled via CSS @media queries, aka "[responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
element { background-image: url(http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/bgimage.jpg); }

@media (max-width: 622px) {
    element { background-image: none; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still can't get it to work. I have removed js and reference to that in functions.php. I added your CSS and nothing happens when the window resizes. Do I need !important? It looks like the style is coming from my template in-line. I assume I drop the above into my child stylesheet yeah?

Comment: I think the key is the "element" element. what should this be? It's in-line, and displays in the inspector as "element". But using "element in the css doesn't seem to select the property.

Comment: @square_eyes You'll need to target the element with a CSS selector - typically a class or an ID. If you haven't encountered this, start with a basic CSS tutorial first.

Comment: I have, of course. I just am having trouble identifying the element.

Comment: For example, the slider is in the div nest class=bg-img, class=sl-slider-inner, and class=sl-slider-content. Selecting these does not work. e.g. @media (max-width: 622px) {
    .bg-img { background-image: none; }
}

Comment: @square_eyes Give us a link to an example, please.

Comment: @square_eyes Looks like the `background-image` is set as a `style` attribute on the element itself. Add `!important` to the `@media` query and it appears to work.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried !important at various steps, but probably when I had something else wrong :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

can you plz check below code may be it's help you.

Here you get two answers:

1) CSS code:

```
<style>
element {
    background-image: url("http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/bgimage.jpg");
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    element { background-image: none; }
}
</style>
```

2) jQuery code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function checkWidth() {
        //check window width when function call.
        var windowSize = jQuery(window).width();

        if (windowSize <= 767) {
            // remove image for small size window screen.
            jQuery( 'element' ).css('background-image', 'none');
        }else{
            // add image for big size window screen.
            jQuery( 'element' ).css('background-image', 'url(http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/bgimage.jpg)');
        }
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        checkWidth();
        jQuery(window).resize(function(){
            // on window resize call function to check window width.
            checkWidth();
        });
    });
</script>
```